# Fontello social characters appear as strange Asian-type symbols

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, fontello

On my Wordpress, I am using a theme that uses Fontello for the social characters found in the right corner of the red bar at the top of the site.

The characters render properly, as social icons, most of the time.  Sometimes, however, they render as Asian-looking characters instead.  This is in the latest version of Chrome.

Any idea what's going on?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/icons-in-icon-box-are-chinese-characters/#post-230996
OR 
Invalid mime type in server setup for woff files. Should be application/x-font-woff

Comment: Thanks @user3258366 On the link you provided, it says that "Your site url defaults to http://www.wolfeinteractive.com but the fonts are being requested from wolfeinteractive.com
via F12 console in IE11:
src: url(‘http://wolfeinteractive.com/wp-content/themes/enfold/config-templatebuilder/avia-template-builder/assets/fonts/entypo-fontello.eot?v=2′);

I adjusted my site url to get it to work in IE11."  Any idea where I would adjust this?  Or, if it's an invalid mime type, how do I know this and go about fixing it?  Thanks!